# NextJs & Typescript - Get cookie in pages router - TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, next.js

In a NextJs App with `pages` router, in `getServerSideProps` I want to get the value of a cookie, as described [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/next-request#getname), but the Typescript compiler reports the following error:

`TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.`

The code I've tried:

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  // Destructure context
  const {
    req,
    query
  } = context;

  // TS Error
  const cookieA = req.cookies.get('A');

  // works
  const cookieA = req.cookies.A;
}
```

`req` is type:
`req: IncomingMessage & { cookies: NextApiRequestCookies }`

and `NextApiRequestCookies`  is:

```
export type NextApiRequestCookies = Partial<{
    [key: string]: string;
}>;
```

TS Error:
`TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.`

Comment: The Partial<T> around the 'NextApiRequestCookies' will make all its attributes optional, so maybe something like `const cookieA = req.cookies?.get('A')` might work?

Comment: can you try optional chaining `const cookieA = req?.cookies?.get('A');`